# Can't ping my IP address

Tags: 14.04, firewall, ip

I cant ping my own IP address for my machine running Ubuntu. I have tried to ping the machine with an external VPS but I still have had no luck. I have opened port 80 (TCP) even though I don't think this is necessary. I believe its something to do with my firewall settings but I can't figure it out.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ping` uses something called ICMP packets, what are completely unrelated to TCP packets, such as the ones carrying an HTTP payload.

If you want ping (and other IP protocols that may depend on ICMP) to work, you have to configure the firewall to pass ICMP packets (perhaps filtering only those that are of interest to you, see below) and also the replies that are generated from these packets. (With the right firewall you may also be able to keep state, even though ICMP is *essentially* stateless. But this is not essential for ping to work.)

I was going to add the ICMP packet types you want to pass, but they are already discussed on security.se: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/22711/is-it-a-bad-idea-for-a-firewall-to-block-icmp

In general, you want something like this (this is super hand-waving, with only the relevant details):

[Host A] <--(internet or untrusted network)--> [Firewall] <--[Host B]-->

The traffic between Host A and Host B is filtered depending on the nature of the traffic, and the state of that traffic. Sometimes Host B and the Firewall are the same. It doesn't really make much difference, as the Firewall itself is *sort of* a virtual host in some regards.

For different types of ICMP payloads can be sent from Host A to a network that it knows is on or behind the Firewall (it doesn't know which, generally). This traffic has to be passed by the Firewall, sent to Host B, and the reply from Host B has to be received as part of that conversation, NATted, and sent back out to Host A.

So, this traffic has to be passed going *both* ways, which sometimes matters to firewalls.

The first thing to check is if ICMP packets of the type we are interested in (your references here and in the comments says which ones we care about) are actually being passed by the Firewall and sent on to Host B. There will be some logging or interface of some sort that allows us to inspect and query the Firewall, I'm sure.

Once we know this traffic is passing, we need to make sure it is making it to Host B (or passed through to the IP stack on the localhost) and that the reply is also being passed.

The details of "how to make iptables work" is sort of beyond the scope of this question, but others might have more hints for you. Or perhaps those details may be found in another SO answer.

One trick is to save your firewall rules in a file, and create a new ruleset that is basically "pass everything in and log, NAT everything out and log" which you enable for testing. Then see if the pings are getting through at all. i.e., prove it is the firewall that is the problem.

Comment: Hello thanks for you reply! I have followed this tutorial 'http://crybit.com/iptables-rules-for-icmp/' but I still can't ping my IP. If I ping the IP internally I get this displayed on my screen once: "PING IP (IP) 56(84) bytes of data.
"

Comment: This is going to be tricky to troubleshoot without a much more detailed picture of your network topology, and where these two hosts are in relation to each other. Specifics about your iptables config will probably be necessary at some point, I suppose, though I am not particularly well-versed with iptables. One of the first steps will probably be enabled iptables logging so you can see which rules are in play, and which ones are dropping packets.